# Can I control precision for geography when outputting as xml

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I select my geography field and output as xml, the precision is shorter. How do I make it use all digits as stored in the column?

```
SELECT cast(mylocation.Lat as nvarchar(max)) as latitude from mytable FOR XML RAW;

For example, 
Field value is: 32.2117407685126
XML shows: <row mylocation="32.2117" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST as DECIMAL instead

```
SELECT cast(mylocation.Lat as DECIMAL(19,13)) as latitude from mytable FOR XML RAW;
```

I assumed that the scale (max to the right of your decimal) is 13 because this is what your data shows. The length of 19 total will give you 6 to the left, but if my geography is OK that should be acceptable.